# why maven liquibase:diff -DdiffExcludeObjects parameter does not work

Tags: liquibase

I have a project that is using liquibase for database sync. When I use maven liquibase for generating a changelog, I want to exclude some database objects whose names start with `oauth_`

My maven goal is like this

```
liquibase:diff -DdiffExcludeObjects="table:oauth_.*"
```

But when I execute the goal, the generated changelog includes these changesets:

```
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-4">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_access_token"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-5">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_approvals"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-6">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_client_details"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-7">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_client_token"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-8">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_code"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1470077228335-9">
    <dropTable tableName="oauth_refresh_token"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of liquibase? This functionality was introduced in [3.3.2](http://www.liquibase.org/2015/01/liquibase-3-3-2-released.html). Just to make sure...

Comment: I am using version 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be just the name of the property. Documentation indicates that the property should be `exludeObjects` not `diffExcludeObjects`.

Answer (score 1):

mvn liquibase:diff -Dliquibase.diffExcludeObjects=oauth_*

Answer (score 1):

**The correct answer:**

```
mvn liquibase:diff -Dliquibase.diffExcludeObjects="table:oauth_.*"
```

with `-Dliquibase.` is Parameter prefix.

More parameter in [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_diff.html)