# Liquibase generate change log on db based on table name prefix

Tags: java, database-migration, maven-plugin, liquibase

Can I generate Liquibase changelog from a DB based on table name prefix.

Example:
If I have a DB schema and it has following tables:

```
abc
abcd
abcdef
xyz
```

I just want to generate ChangeLog for tables starting with "abc". So changelog for tables

> abc,
>   abcd,
>   abcdef

Can someone help me if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me on `Windows 10`:

`liquibase.properties`:

```
changeLogFile=dbchangelog.xml
classpath=C:/Program\ Files/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase?serverTimezone=UTC
username=root
password=password
schemas=liquibase
includeSchema=true
includeTablespace=true
includeObjects=table:persons
```

C:\Users\username\Desktop>`liquibase generateChangeLog`

```
Liquibase Community 4.0.0 by Datical
Starting Liquibase at 11:34:35 (version 4.0.0 #19 built at 2020-07-13 19:45+0000)
Liquibase command 'generateChangeLog' was executed successfully.
```

You can download mysql-connector [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.20), find the `generateChangeLog` documentation [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) and more information on `includeObjects` [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/including-and-excluding-objects-from-a-database.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with maven or liquibase command line if you're using liquibase version > 3.3.2.

Take a look at the [release notes](http://www.liquibase.org/2015/01/liquibase-3-3-2-released.html)

> Liquibase 3.3.2 is officially released. It is primarily a bugfix
>   release, but has one major new feature: object
>   diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog object filtering.
>   includeObjects/excludeObjects logic
>
> You can now set an includeObjects or excludeObjects paramter on the
>   command line or Ant. For maven, the parameteres are diffExcludeObjects
>   and diffIncludeObjects. The format for these parameters are:
>
> ```
> An object name (actually a regexp) will match any object whose name matches the regexp.
> A type:name syntax that matches the regexp name for objects of the given type
> If you want multiple expressions, comma separate them
> The type:name logic will be applied to the tables containing columns, indexes, etc.
> ```
>
> NOTE: name comparison is case sensitive. If you want insensitive
>   logic, use the (?i) regexp flag.
>
> Example Filters:
>
> ```
> “table_name” will match a table called “table_name” but not “other_table” or “TABLE_NAME”
> “(i?)table_name” will match a table called “table_name” and “TABLE_NAME”
> “table_name” will match all columns in the table table_name
> “table:table_name” will match a table called table_name but not a column named table_name
> “table:table_name, column:*._lock” will match a table called table_name and all columns that end with “_lock”
> ```

So try using `excludeObjects` or `includeObjects` parameters with `generateChangeLog` command

**UPDATE**

I've used liquibase command line, and this command does the trick (for mysql database):

```
liquibase 
--changeLogFile=change.xml 
--username=username 
--password=password 
--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
--url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
--classpath=mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar 
--includeObjects="table:abc.*" 
generateChangeLog
```

Comment: I am running following command mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -DincludeObjects="abc*" but still facing issues

Comment: You have to write -DincludeObjects="table:abc*" as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706429/why-maven-liquibasediff-ddiffexcludeobjects-parameter-does-not-work

Comment: @AvikKesari  I've updated the answer. You need to use `--includeObjects="table:abc.*"`